# Trying to use proccess.js and javascript in html

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know much but I have to create my own website and I am confused as to why it doesnt work. I've viewed the website http://mg8.org/processing/ and wish to put their javascript into my own page. I have their two references files in my directory.

And use these lines

```
<head>
<title>Brotobro Bittorrent</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="processing-0.5.packed.js"></script>

</head>
```

And then later in the page

< canvas src="bt.pjs" width="450" height ="450">< /canvas>

I've also visited their website and copy and pasted their copy into my own page and it still doesn't work if you wish to visit it http://www.duke.edu/~ajb60/bt.html.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error on your page:

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word"
```

Resolve the error, and the script might load. Use firebug w/firefox to debug your webpage or load the page in chrome and hit F12.

I got your example working, just copy the following script to the same directory with bt.html:

http://mg8.org/processing/bt.pjs

Your animation will load.

Comment: That is not the issue as on my other page with the script doesn't hit that problem

Comment: what other page? http://mg8.org/processing/ or http://www.duke.edu/~ajb60/bt.html? The bt.pjs script on the two sites are also not identical. This is on purpose?